# Question about proof that sub $*$-algebra of $B(H)$ is strongly dense in bicommutant.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

Consider following fragment from Murphy's "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory":

[image]

In the proof of lemma 4.1.4, why does $u(x) \in K$ follow from $pu = up?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will show that $u(K) \subseteq K$. Let $y \in K$, then $p(y) = y$ and
$$u(y) = u(p(y)) = p(u(y)) \in K.$$

Now, as $id_H \in A$, we have $x = id_H (x) \in K$ from the definition of $A$. Hence, $u(x) \in K$.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that I could use that $A$ contains the identity!